# Multivariate XTS as argument works with lapply but not mclapply

Tags: r, multicore, xts

I have a function which works with `lapply` but returns an error if I try it with `mclapply`.  The argument to the function is a multivariate XTS.  Here is a sample:

```
library(quantmod)
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(4)

test <- function(x){
  return(mean(x))
}

myEnv <- new.env()
getSymbols(c("^GSPC", "^RUT"), env=myEnv)
data <- do.call(merge, c(eapply(myEnv, Ad), all=TRUE))

lapply(data, test)
mclapply(data, test)
```

`lapply` returns the results as expected but `mclapply` returns:

```
Error in `[.xts`(X, seq(i, length(X), by = cores)) : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Can someone help me out here?  Thanks.

#### Session Info

```
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] doMC_1.2.5      multicore_0.1-7 iterators_1.0.6 foreach_1.4.0   quantmod_0.3-22 TTR_0.21-1      xts_0.9-0       zoo_1.7-9      
[9] Defaults_1.1-1 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] codetools_0.2-8 grid_2.15.2     lattice_0.20-10 Rcpp_0.9.15     tools_2.15.2
```

Comment: Your example works for me using R-2.15.2, xts_0.8-9 (from R-Forge), and `parallel::mclapply`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich No joy for me.  I upgraded to R-2.15.2 and xts_0.9 and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xts` objects are funny in the sense that:

```
length(data)
# [1] 3010
data[3010]
# Error in `[.xts`(data, 3010) : subscript out of bounds
```

and that, `mclapply` does not like...

You'll find that `mclapply(as.list(data), test)` will work, although the documentation says:

> `X`:   a vector (atomic or list) or an expressions vector. Other objects (including classed objects) will be coerced by `as.list`.

Go figure... It's probably worth mentioning to the authors.